# смена имени канала не работает после двух раз

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

есть код, смена имени не работает больше двух раз, после двух раз не удаляется канал и не работают другие функции связанные с голосовыми каналами

```
@client.command()

async def setup(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id == 426376741028888576 or ctx.author.id == 229695537337729024:
        for guild in client.guilds:
            vcategory = await guild.create_category(name=f'название')
            convoice = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f'коннект', category = vcategory)
            txtchannel = await guild.create_text_channel(name=f'log', category = vcategory)

            #создание канала 

            @client.event
            async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after):
                if after.channel == convoice:
                    for guild in client.guilds:
                        chan_category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, category = vcategory)
                        new_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f'{member.display_name}', category = vcategory)
                        await member.move_to(new_channel)
                        await new_channel.set_permissions(member, connect=True, mute_members=True, move_members=True, manage_channels=True)

                        if before.channel == None:
                            await ctx.send (f'{member.mention} вышел')
                        elif before.channel == new_channel:
                            await ctx.send (f'{member.mention} зашел')

                        client.remove_command ('vname')
                        @client.command()
                        async def vname(ctx, amount: str):
                            await new_channel.edit(name=amount)

                        client.remove_command ('vlimit')
                        @client.command()
                        async def vlimit(ctx, amount: int):
                                await new_channel.edit(user_limit=amount)


                        def check (x, y, z):
                            return len(new_channel.members) == 0



                        await client.wait_for('voice_state_update',check=check)
                        await new_channel.delete()

    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'ещё чего :rage:'))
```

Comment: Как часто меняете имя канала?

Comment: я проводил тест. И если делать всё сразу и быстро, думаю надо поставить кд

Comment: Не уверен сколько сейчас ограничение, но когда то было около раза в 5-10 минут. Так что кд нужно делать.

Comment: можете показать как сделать это в моём коде?

Comment: Сделайте переменную с отметкой времени последнего успешного использования команды и проверяйте разницу во времени.